# What CDNs are there, which host javascript libraries, frameworks, styles and fonts?

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks, cdn

I want to make a list of javascript, css, fonts CDNs available today.

Can you please **specify URLs of those CDNs** (without framework references)?

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/about specifically says "Don't ask about requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc."

Comment: There's Google, and they also have a search engine that will answer this by just typing in "CDN script I'm looking for" etc.

Comment: Hmm, will it qualify for *asking for a list of things* if I rephrase the question to *What CDNs can I use to host the js frameworks?*

Comment: @adeneo I am not looking for a **specific script**, I want to make a list of available CDNs out there in the wild. I've listed all I have googled so far. Maybe my google-fu is different?

Comment: How come that this question can be **opinion-based** or **lead to discussions**?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I have found those:

## Public CDNs

CDN for Open Source libraries. Everybody can get access.

- **Google CDN** - https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/
- **Microsoft CDN** - http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx
- **JSDelivr** - http://www.jsdelivr.com/
- **MaxCDN** - http://www.maxcdn.com/
- **Bootstrap CDN** - http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/
- **CreateJS CDN** - http://code.createjs.com/
- **CDNjs** - http://cdnjs.com/

## Private CDNs

CDN for private usage.

- **Coral CDN** - http://www.coralcdn.org/
- **Swarm CDN** - http://swarmcdn.com/
- **CDN.net** - http://www.cdn.net/